# remove 8080 port from tomcat url

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using httpd and tomcat for my web application,
so i want to remove 8080 port which is coming in my url.

i tried following things

1. Made `<Connector port="80"` in server.xml but its not working.
2. Used Proxypass in httpd.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName myapp.com
ServerAlias www.myapp.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /MyAppPath http://localhost:8080
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080`

but both of the things are not working.

whenever i am hitting www.mysite.com its showing apache 2.2 page.
To reach out to mysite every time i need to put www.mysite.com:8080/

please guide.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From your config it seems you would have to hit `www.mysite.com/MyAppPath` to go to your tomcat app. Is that working or not?

Comment: yes its working if only i hit www.mysite.com:8080/MyApp  @arco444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by pointing tomcat to 80 and stoped the httpd service.

Worked for me.